# How do you map old FCC license classes to the new 3-class system?

Tags: united-states, license, fcc

A lot of resources, including this ubiquitous (and otherwise very useful) [band chart](http://www.arrl.org/files/file/Regulatory/Band%20Chart/Band%20Chart.pdf) from the Amateur Radio Relay League (ARRL) refer to the older FCC license system which had Novice, Technician, General, Advanced, and Amateur Extra licenses. Now Technician, General, and Amateur Extra are the only license types.

For the purposes of using resources like that ARRL chart which refer to the older license, what is the mapping between the old and new system? For instance, can I assume that anything previously labeled as "Advanced" is now "Amateur Extra"? Or is part of what was once "Advanced" now "Amateur Extra" and the remainder "General", etc?

Comment: In my experience external links tend to break over time, so for posterity's sake - the linked ARRL band chart was last updated in late 2020 but still uses the older FCC license system, whereas at this point in 2022 the FCC has a 3-class amateur radio license system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That chart isn't out of date. Advanced and Novice are still Advanced and Novice, and their privileges are as indicated on the chart. The FCC stopped issuing *new* Advanced and Novice licenses around the year 2000, but anyone who has one is permitted to renew it indefinitely.

47 CFR 97.9(a): "The classes of amateur operator license grants are: Novice, Technician, General, Advanced, and Amateur Extra"

97.17(a): "No new license grant will be issued for a Novice or Advanced Class operator/primary station."

97.301: Lists the band privileges of each license class, including Advanced and Novice. This, together with the following few sections, is what the ARRL chart displays graphically.

And a few other sections which say that "the holder of a Technician, General, Advanced, or Amateur Extra class license" can do something or other, which means that a Novice *cannot*.

Comment: Thanks. Oh right, I know the old licenses are grandfathered in until they expire but I'm earning licenses under the newer system, so I'm just trying to map the old license bands to the new system. That makes sense regarding novice. So the answers for Advanced must be in the federal code and I'll go grab it then we can add it to the answer.

Comment: There is no "newer" system,.  They just stopped issuing some the old classes and continued issuing others.  You can't map them, because they still exist and still have their unique privileges.

Comment: Oh! OK, I didn’t realize that. I will accept the answer as the solution.